# How to boost a phrase matching but just in certain field?

Tags: elasticsearch, match-phrase

I want to boost a query if its by match phrasing but I want it to search only in a certain field. So far I have the following query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "_all": {
              "query": "string",
              "boost": 5
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

but this returns several results since I'm not specifying the field where it should search in. I tried this other approach:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "_all": {
              "query": "string",
              "fields": [
                "filed_name"
              ],
              "boost": 5
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

but I get the error

> [match] query does not support [fields]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [multi match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) query and use `phrase type` to do `match_phrase` in specific fields.

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "some string",
      "fields": ["title","summary"],
      "type": "phrase"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you @ChintanShah25! that's what I ended up doing actually.
You can also include a fuzziness parameter this way.
Eg:

{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "some string",
      "fields": ["title","summary"],
      "type": "phrase",
      "fuzziness": "AUTO"
    }
  }
}